# In this example can UPDATE statements be combined?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I quite often have rows of code like the following:

```
    UPDATE my_table SET name = 'x'  WHERE Original =  'a'
    UPDATE my_table SET name = 'y' WHERE Original =  'b' 
    UPDATE my_table SET name = 'z' WHERE Original = 'c'  
    UPDATE my_table SET name = 'k' WHERE Original = 'd' 
    UPDATE my_table SET name = 'm' WHERE Original = 'e'  
    UPDATE my_table SET name = 'n' WHERE Original = 'f'
```

Can I combine/shorten this code into one UpDate statement - or are they best just left as they are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET name = 
    CASE 
        WHEN Original = 'a' THEN 'x' 
        WHEN Original = 'b' THEN 'y' 
        ... 
    END
```

That will update EVERY row. So if there's an Original value you haven't specified, it will be set to NULL. So you might want to limit the update to just those you want to update, with a WHERE clause, like so:

```
WHERE Original IN ('a', 'b', ...)
```

OR, as an alternative, you could use an ELSE statement, which leaves the name value as is, if it doesn't have a match in the WHEN statements, like so:

```
    CASE 
        WHEN Original = 'a' THEN 'x' 
        WHEN Original = 'b' THEN 'y' 
        ... 
        ELSE name
    END
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `case` statement:

```
UPDATE  my_table 
SET     name = 
        case Original
        when 'a' then 'x'
        when 'b' then 'y'
        ...
        else name -- Preserve original
        end
```

The `else` clause makes sure you're not modifying a `name` if it's not matched in the `case`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [table value constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382%28v=sql.105%29) and a from clause, if these values aren't already in a table:

```
update mt set name = t.name
from
    my_table mt
        inner join
    (values
        ('a','x'),
        ('b','y'),
        ('c','z'),
        ('d','k'),
        ('e','m'),
        ('f','n')
    ) t(original,name)
        on
            mt.Original = t.original
```

Comment: +1 thanks for alternative: the `values(...)` section is the TVC? are these good in terms of performance

Comment: Yes, it's the `VALUES` that's a table value constructor. I've not got any data on performance - obviously, if you were specifying a *huge* number of rows, it may be beneficial to place them in an actual table with indexing. (TVC is limited to 1000 rows anyway)